# Difference between X-Pack and SearchGuard in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack, search-guard

I am setting up user authentication when accessing kibana. I would like to have a login prompt whenever user hits the kibana URL.

I found x-pack and searchguard manages user authentication, I am not sure of the difference. I am actually using reverse proxy, should I be using the searchguard to manage user authentication?

I am confuse between the x-pack and searchguard, apology if any info stated wrongly in the message

Answer (score -1):

Both X-Pack and Search Guard are plugins for Elasticsearch. X-Pack is a complete plugin which includes security among other things. Search Guard is the open source alternative to X-Pack in securing the elastic stack. Since X-Pack is a paid plugin, its free version doesn't include security, you get however a 30 days trial.

At the end, both offer more or less the same in terms of security.

Comment: Agus, can I check with you is X-pack kerberos realm free to use?